# Map Stream for get count of values in a nested HashMap

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

pseudo code,

```
Map <String, HashMap<String,List<Submission>>> assignmentMap = new HashMap();

Map <String, List<Submission>> submissionMap = new HashMap();

List <Submission> ls = new ArrayList();
ls.add(new Submission("student1"));
ls.add(new Submission("student2"));

submissionMap.put("studentSubmissions", ls);

assignmentMap.put("assignmentid1", submissionMap);
```

Finally I want to get the count of all studentSubmissions (there can e other types too like instrutorSubmission etc) belong to assignment 1. In this case 2. How can I write a code with Java 8 Streams to achieve it?

Comment: Before you even *contemplate* using streams, stop using *raw* generics, e.g. first line should be `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> assignmentMap = new HashMap<>();` --- Second line doesn't have any type parameters at all, so that won't work well with streams!!

Comment: What is `map2`?

Comment: corrected the code

Comment: The list `ls` is of type `String`. However, `new Submission("student1")` would return the object of `Submission` type. Please edit the question appropriately.

Comment: @Harshana, if you edit your question in response to a comment, do reply back so that the user is notified of the edit.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way to count all the `Submission`'s done by `studentSubmissions` for `assignmentid1`.

```
long a = assignmentMap.entrySet().stream().
            filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("assignmentid1")).
            flatMap(i -> i.getValue().entrySet().stream()).
            filter(k -> k.getKey().equals("studentSubmissions")).
            flatMap(j -> j.getValue().stream()).
            count();
```

If you remove both the filters, you'll get the count of all the `Submisson` for each type of `Submission` for each `assignment`.

However, I'd like to make a comment regarding the nesting of a `Collection` (here a `List`) inside a `Map` inside another `Map`. Nesting to such an extent has following cons:

- The readabality of code is damaged severely.
- The stream operations have to be unnecessarily complex as you can observe the solution to just count the `Submission` list.

In order to avoid such nesting you should re-consider your `Class` design. To differentiate the type of `Submission` based on a `String` value might not be the best choice. You can go for `Child` classes for `StudentSubmission` and `InstructorSubmission` that will extend the `Submission` parent class.

Comment: @Harshana, does this answer your question?